# Lost connection to MySQL server when using multiple connections

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to run a multithreaded script.

1 thread works fine. However, when I go to 2 threads, it will execute a few SQL commands, then it will stop with:

```
OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')
```

And the second thread will stop too:

```
OperationalError: (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')
```

I've read lots of documentation on this and some of the things I've done is:

- checked the error log, nothing was there other than shutdown and boot notifications
- I've increased `max_allowed_packet` to 64M. My query is not that long (inserting 100 URLs to database)
- Set `connect_timeout` to 30
- Set `net_read_timeout` to 60

My script is in python and is quite lengthy but I don't close the connections if that's what you're looking for.

Both cursors are made by this code (run in the `__init__` section of each `threading.Thread` class:

```
self.db = MySQLdb.connect(my details)
self.db.autocommit(True)
self.cursor = db.cursor()
```

The log-error file is as follows:

```
140820 21:41:41 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Normal shutdown

140820 21:41:41 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
140820 21:41:41  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
140820 21:41:44  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 0 44243
140820 21:41:44 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

140820 21:41:44 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
140820 21:41:45 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
140820 21:41:45 [Warning] '--log' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use ''--general_log'/'--general_log_file'' instead.
140820 21:41:45  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
140820 21:41:45  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140820 21:41:45  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 44243
140820 21:41:45 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
140820 21:41:45 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.1.71-log'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution
140820 21:45:36 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Normal shutdown

140820 21:45:36 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
140820 21:45:36  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
140820 21:45:40  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 0 44243
140820 21:45:40 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

140820 21:45:40 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
140820 21:45:41 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
140820 21:45:41 [Warning] '--log' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use ''--general_log'/'--general_log_file'' instead.
140820 21:45:41  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
140820 21:45:41  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140820 21:45:41  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 44243
140820 21:45:41 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
140820 21:45:41 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.1.71-log'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution
```

Any ideas why 2 threads would raise an issue, but not 1 thread?

Thanks so much

Comment: Are both threads communicating at the same time on the same socket?

Comment: How do you organize this, as two separate connections, or the same connection you trigger multiple times. Can you please provide some source code?

Comment: Added the cursor and connection code.

Comment: Most likely case is that one of the queries takes very long time to execute and at the same time the other handle is idle. When that happens, eventually your socket connection to mysql will be closed, either by MySQL due to inactivity or due to connection error between the script and mysql server.

Comment: Each query takes 3 seconds at max for the reference.

Comment: It may be, but it also may be that they is a long chain of them ran from one thread, blocking the other from working, and then the other gets its turn - it has been long enough to get disconnected. Or it may be just connection is giving you hard time, hard to say when we know close to nothing about the problem.

Comment: It would be nice if the error log spit something more accurate out.

Comment: `SET GLOBAL LOG_WARNINGS = 2;` to increase verbosity in the error logs.